# OSX running app acts differently from running on terminal

Tags: macos, debugging, go

I have written an app for OSX (Sierra) in Go (lang) with the GUI powered by the [Golang QT binding therecipe/qt](https://github.com/therecipe/qt). When I build the app and run it from the command prompt with command `open $(pwd)/myapp.app` I get a terminal output while its running, and everything works fine.

When I double click on the app in finder to run it, I obviously don't have access to the console to see debugging, but in parts of the app that work fine in the GUI when I run from console (clicking on things, etc), it crashes the app when run by clicking on it.

I realise people don't know what the app is, and without seeing where in the app it crashes, they can't help me. What I am after is some ideas about debugging it, for instance:

1. Outputting logs to a text file and tailing the text file to watch as it is written to
2. Connecting a debugger to the application by the process, perhaps I can discover where it crashes. This doesn't sound straight forward
3. Is there a way to attach to a console of an application run like this to see what it is outputting?

Any ideas appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: can you tell in your app is it launched from the terminal or not? If you can distinguish non terminal launches then you can disable that log output or redirect it to a file...

Comment: In the end I added an embedded database (boltdb) and viewed the logs/errors in the database to discover the issue. I didn't know that an app would get different env vars to an app run from terminal - good to know!

Comment: If anyone is interested how I got on with all this (Gui dev in Go), I've put together a writeup here https://github.com/amlwwalker/got-qt